# Asp.Net framework not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

After using command `dotnet new mvc` on a folder, than I tried to run it through VS Code and I got the following error:

> You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
>   Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
>   to help you develop and test your applications.
>
> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>
> The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
>
> - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>       /opt/dotnet/
> - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
> - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
>
> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
>
> The program '[4090] AspProject.dll' has exited with code 150 (0x96).

Here is the output of `dotnet --info`:

> Version:   2.1.300
>   Commit:    adab45bf0c
>
> Runtime Environment:
>    OS Name:     manjaro
>    OS Version:
>    OS Platform: Linux
>    RID:         linux-x64
>    Base Path:   /opt/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/
>
> Host (useful for support):
>     Version: 2.1.0
>
> Commit:  caa7b7e2ba
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     2.1.300 [/opt/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:
>     Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
>     https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

As you can see, my dotnet version is 2.1.

I saw that other people had already had this problem, but all the solutions I tried didn't work for me.

Comment: Check your installation of Microsoft Visual Studio Components

Comment: There is too much missing here. List all the steps, ie dotnet restore  etc. Show a printout that proves 2.1 is installed etc. Post exect error message.

Comment: Could you try uninstall and reinstall .[NET Core 2.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem in Windows 7
so 
I am uninstall **.NET Core SDKs 2.1.300**
and make update for windows and install
 **.NET Core SDKs 2.1.2** from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.201)

I don't know about your OS,,, I see and solve it yesterday